# List of services used in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Please how can get the list of all services I am using.

I have gone to Service Quotas at
`https://ap-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=ap-east-1`
on the dashboard. I could see a list of Items e.g. EC2, VPC, RDS, Dynamo etc but I did not understand what is there.

As I did not request for some of the services I am seeing I even went into budget at
`https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=ap-east-1#/budgets`
and also credits. Maybe I can get the  services I have been given credits to use
`https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=ap-east-1#/budgets`?

Also, how can I stop any service which I do not want?

The Billing service is not giving me tangible information also. I do not want the bill to pile up before I start taking needed steps.

Is there a location where I can see all services I am using or maybe there is a code I can enter somewhere which would produce such result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Config Resource Inventory feature.

AWS Config will discover resources that exist in your account, record their current configuration, and capture any changes to these configurations. Config will also retain configuration details for resources that have been deleted. A comprehensive snapshot of all resources and their configuration attributes provides a complete inventory of resources in your account.

https://aws.amazon.com/config/

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy answer on this one, as there is not an AWS service that you can use to do this out of the box (yet).
There are some AWS services that you can use to get you close, like:
AWS Config (as suggested by @kepils)
Another option is to use [Resource Groups and Tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/creating-a-resource-group.html) to list all resources within a region within account (as described [in this answer](https://serverfault.com/q/688836/614823)).

In both cases however, the issue is that both Config and Resource Groups come with the same limitation - they can't see all AWS services on their own.

Another option would be to use a third party tool to do this, if your end goal is to find what do you currently have running in your account like [aws-inventory](https://github.com/nccgroup/aws-inventory) or [cloudmapper](https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper)

On the second part of your question on how to stop any services which you don't want you can do the following:

1. Don't grant excessive permissions to your users. If someone needs to work on EC2 instances, then their IAM role and respective policy should allow only that instead of for example full access.
2. You can limit the scope and services permitted for use within account by creating [Service Control Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) which are allowing only the specific resources you plan to use.
3. Set-up an [AWS Budget Notifications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-set-aws-budget-when-paying-with-aws-credits/) and potentially [AWS Budget Actions.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cloud-financial-management/get-started-with-aws-budgets-actions/)